# Update points coordinates directly on the map using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have many locations or points overlapped each other, so is there a way using QGIS that I can update locations directly on the map using QGIS features, please let me know as I'm new to GIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open the data table and select the feature you would like to move (i.e. one of the overlapped features). You can click on the "Zoom to selection" option (see picture below in a red square) to zoom into the selected feature.

[image]

Then you just have to start editing the layer:

[image]

And use the tool to move features (drag and drop):

[image]